# Image shrinks when applying padding to it as the browser window is widened

Tags: html, css

When I add padding to a menu button that I will be using to display a drop-down menu, it shrinks the dimensions of the image. As the browser window is widened it continues to shrink until it can no longer be seen. In the below piece of code, it is sized correctly, but if i add any sort of padding to it the problem occurs. The ul is hidden at the screen size that the menu button is shown and vice versa.

```css
.menu-button {
  float: right;
  margin: 8px 3% 0 0;
  min-width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#landing {
  background: url('../img/coffee-laptop.jpg') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="landing">
  <header class="group">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">Ben Quartermaine</a></h1>
    <a class="menu-button"><img src="img/icons/menu.svg"></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#process">Process</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: try using position absolute on the image that will ignore the padding of the button

Comment: Displaying it like block or inline-block is better than having absolute positioning.

Comment: Could you please add the padding that causes the problem?

Comment: I tried to add padding: 10px to the .menu-button class

Comment: The snippet does not demonstrate the problem. Can you change it so that it does?